# updated android studio, now every app crashes? (also using mac)

Tags: android, ios, macos, android-studio, corruption

hi new developer on android and i just updated my android studio (due to parse requiring this version) with my logcat prompting me to update. due to all the updates that i had to install my apps will not run. 
so i wiped android studio clean from my mac and reinstalled it again, in turn this allowed me to update my android studios with the latest version, where ActionBarActivity has been replaced with AppCompatActivity and an extra class which extends Application. don't understand why this is needed?
i saved all my applications from my pervious version to run on the updated version of android studio to find that the same problem i had last time had arisen, where i am prompted to update each app to the new specs to find out the app is not compatible and crashes all the apps. 
to make it even worse every time i run an app it tells me to delete the app but warns me not to? which i 100% don't understand.

please can some one help me understand why this is happening and what i need to do to solve this absurd issue.

thanks in advance.

screenshots are shown below of what happened in chronological order
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLaZ4.jpg

Comment: The screenshots aren't 100% helpful. Why not use build tools 22.0.1? Or target those build tools. Make sure everything is targeting correctly and that it's pointing to the right directories

Comment: Since your application is built with new buildtools the previous version application has the same coordinates(package name) as the new version, Uninstall the application from your device and try again, if application crashes post your logcat.